# Bootstrap 4 : Set Width of Column Width Fixed Position Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 4 based web page with 1 row which has 3 columns. I want the 1st and 3rd columns to have a fixed position and the 2nd column to be scrollable.

```
<div class="container" style="align-content:center;background-color:red;">
    <div class="form-row" style=" margin: 0px;" >
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;" >
                    <div style="position:fixed;">                    
                        Alapus berihal aralori nog abosiman to lere sot. Tec rihew elicip eho ma gub? Atiyi fe emanoto urigifie cep corike? Ino oraled efoponay to cinit opotare. Tadedo pet rico ocodum yetej tupe ime havi bod huwese, esofahe esereho hihuriet ner ge. Laha rig hikede ri totonic porac. Ebacep yiribos toriel delu riti iter. Cepit atobiteg tavet icut ariyase cilayon.

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:red;" >
                    Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir.
                    Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir.
                    Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir.
                    Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir.
                    Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir.

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:yellow;"  >            
                    <div style="position:fixed;">
                       Cegeh na rasi nitora sep lim ded so rar? Po tosula iwe ciyirif; iro seri la nenegac ralala meralak, nomir na lerorer! Lita resonop eropem enulose mi rer ne tacacal yumo calos. Dic teril satec yel wupip rar: Keye hipoce egol ecimi ra cienet. Yohicem niran sor naqetar odecafel eso ronu tunerig sos: Musedu roy tegovi hu reru inaca. Lo onobeda ategat de. Ikikosen polie re uweme ronepo. Mitif reqepu sel. Fubiel pac madotil pip, nedupa rotolin re deciso riciho; tenabir rakira nay asaluti yer reci penede iepaso.
                    </div>


                </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

The content of the 3rd column exceeds the column. If I remove position:fixed, the content stays within the column, but the column becomes scrollable. If I use position:sticky, I don't know what to set the top attribute to without using javascript. Does anyone know how I can keep the content of the column fixed while keeping it within the column?

Comment: your 3 columns have long content, if you make only the second column scrollable, how do you think the user can view the content for other columns?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do something like this :

```
<div class="col-md-3 h-100">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3 h-100 scrolling-content">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3 h-100">...</div>
```

And in you css :

```
.scrolling-content {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .box {
      overflow: scroll;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" style="align-content: center; background-color: red;">
    <div class="form-row row" style=" margin: 0px;">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: white;">
        Alapus berihal aralori nog abosiman to lere sot. Tec rihew elicip eho ma gub? Atiyi fe emanoto urigifie cep corike? Ino oraled efoponay to cinit opotare. Tadedo pet rico ocodum yetej tupe ime havi bod huwese, esofahe esereho hihuriet ner ge. Laha rig
        hikede ri totonic porac. Ebacep yiribos toriel delu riti iter. Cepit atobiteg tavet icut ariyase cilayon.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 box" style="background-color: red;">
        Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat
        yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir. Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la
        semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir. Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic
        etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir. Vani vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas?
        Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir. Vani
        vo teco laf. Eninegit uge no rayo no so sucic: Bomage rob tas? Rep sogesas mosen penude za hoyetob pin. Ilil ditolun lisafic etatem aber wah epasa pimev asic lowieso, letadol suriso la semu. Qalonur toru ha osilo herera cacal ciyod non isi? Ler
        cat yisegi. Ale ren geneva; lac pogeba adi nome layedir.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: yellow;">
        Cegeh na rasi nitora sep lim ded so rar? Po tosula iwe ciyirif; iro seri la nenegac ralala meralak, nomir na lerorer! Lita resonop eropem enulose mi rer ne tacacal yumo calos. Dic teril satec yel wupip rar: Keye hipoce egol ecimi ra cienet. Yohicem niran
        sor naqetar odecafel eso ronu tunerig sos: Musedu roy tegovi hu reru inaca. Lo onobeda ategat de. Ikikosen polie re uweme ronepo. Mitif reqepu sel. Fubiel pac madotil pip, nedupa rotolin re deciso riciho; tenabir rakira nay asaluti yer reci penede
        iepaso.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```